# TYPO3: Get language code

Tags: typo3

As far as I know, there are two ways to retrieve the current (front-end) language:

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->config['config']['language']
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_uid
```

If the latter is 2, then the config value is, say, 'dk'.
However, if the language UID is 0, then the first variable returns '' (empty string).

Is there a mapping between `sys_language_uid` and the language code, or in other words, where/how can I find the default language (code)?

Answer (score 1):

Just to go a bit deeper into this: There is a mapping between `sys_language_id` and the language code.

You're setting up languages available for your website through `sys_language` records on your instance root (via list module on "page" uid 0). These records contain a select field `static_lang_isocode` where you choose the corresponding ISO 2-char code for the language record you're creating/editing. This allows fetching the 2-char code for any language uid given.

As long as you've inserted the page languages correctly, you'll have a mapping, so to say. **Except** for uid `0`, as konsolenfreddy wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to initialize the language in TypoScript:

```
config {
    sys_language_uid = 0
    language = de
    locale_all = de_DE.UTF-8
    htmlTag_langKey = de_DE
}

[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
    config {
        sys_language_uid = 1
        language = en
        locale_all = en_EN.UTF-8
        htmlTag_langKey = en_EN
    }
[end]
```

This would default to german and return 'de' in your case

Comment: Yes, I know. I was just curious whether or not there was a way to get the default language code w/o touching the TS config.

Comment: no, there isn't as TYPO3 doesn't know initially which language is the default language, it can be anything.. For that matter in a single language installation it's irrelevant.